# Where are the logs stored when using Hawtio logs and insight-log4j?

Tags: logging, hawtio

I'm researching the [Hawtio Log Plugin](http://hawt.io/plugins/logs/) with the insight-log4j bundle to get the logs of my application in Hawtio.

I would like to know where these logs are stored (memory/disk?) and how many logs are stored (time based/number?), so that I can determine how many resources I need.

The plugin page doesn't mention this and the link to the bundle is broken. On [GitHub](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/master/hawtio-insight-log) I'm not able to find any clues to the storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hawtio does not store logs, it only read from any existing logger such as log4j / slf4j.

So you configure your existing logger as you want, and then the logger plugin from hawtio can read the log lines and show in the web console.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I read your answer I was wondering how the plugin is able to reach my logging. I'm logging only to the console and AFAIK as soon as the logger has logged to the console, the log is gone from the Java process.  
  
But I think I found where the logs are stored, in the class Log4jLogQuery I found the property events, which is a list with a maximum size of 2000. My guess is that it will store the last 2000 log messages in memory.  
  
Is that guess right or am I looking in a wrong direction?

Comment: Yeah it has a little buffer of X last log events